# Is it possible to append 2 jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, here i get an error

```
jQuery([jQuery('<td/>').text('Component'), 
        jQuery('<td/>').text('Value')]).appendTo(my_table)
```

Is it possible append two element to `my_table` object with one action?

Also FYI

```
var my_table = jQuery('<table/>').attr({'class': 'table table-hover table-bordered', 'id': 'parse-result'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two obvious options.

Use `.append` instead - it can take a list of elements to add:

```
my_table.append(
    jQuery(...),
    jQuery(...)
);
```

or use `.add` to combine jQuery lists:

```
jQuery(...).add(jQuery(...)).appendTo(my_table)
```

personally, I'd use the former.  IMHO it's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_table = jQuery('<table/>').attr({'class': 'table table-hover table-bordered', 'id': 'parse-result'});
my_table.append('<td>Component</td>', '<td>Value</td>');
$('body').append(my_table);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3T4W7/

Comment: the middle line needs to have the full jQuery wrap used for each parameter to allow the OP to use the `.text()` methods on the created elements.

Comment: well yes, strictly speaking you've _replaced_ the OP's call to `.text`.  But what if there had been other methods?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$('#myTable').append( //Selects myTable and appends the tr below
    $('<tr></tr>').append( //Creates a new tr element and appends the tds below
        $('<td></td>').text('Cell 1'), //Creates a new td element
        $('<td></td>').text('Cell 2') //Creates a new td element
    )
);
```